# Swagger example post body - how to show JSON Body- Swagger-annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, swagger-ui

Requirement: I have a POST method which takes the input JSON as a String and passes it to another microservice. I don't want to create an Object (Bean) of this input JSON.

method:

```
    @ApiOperation(notes = "example" value = "/example", consumes = ".." , method= "..")
    @RequestMapping(name = "xxx" value ="/hello" ..)
    @ApiResponses(..)
        public @ResponseBody String getXXX (@Apiparam(name="JSONrequest", required = true) @RequestBody String JSONrequest){

    }
```

Problem:
The generated Swagger doesn't show the input as a JSON model where all the JSON attributes are displayed.

Expectation:
I want to display my Swagger Something like this :

[image]

Definately I am missing the key thing. Any thoughts?

Comment: You must define a model if you want to show json schema in swagger-ui I believe.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question but since I haven't found a solution online here how I to customized the example value in the swagger documentation produce automatically by the java annotations.
I use swagger 2.0 and springfox.version 2.10.5.

The Idea is documenting the class of the request parameter that has the `@RequestBody` annotation. for example my method is

```
    @ApiOperation(
              value = "Start ListBuilder extraction",
              response = ExtractionLogEntity.class,
              produces = "application/json"
            )
    @PostMapping("/extraction/start")
    public ExtractionLogEntity startTask(
        @RequestBody(required = true) ExtractionRequest request,
```

In order to expose request json object example I added a    `@ApiModelProperty(example = "...")` annotation to the properties of ExtractionRequest .

```
   @ApiModelProperty(example = "[{ 'field':'value'}]")
    @NotNull
    private  List<ListBuilderFieldEntity> fields;

   @ApiModelProperty(example = "1000")

    private  String ied;
   @ApiModelProperty(example = "US")
    private  String codebase;
```

And that's the result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If changing from `String` to a concrete object is not okay (although that's what I would recommend you to do since it's cleaner), you can try using `@ApiImplicitParams` (check out their [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apiimplicitparam-apiimplicitparams))

```
@ApiOperation(notes = "example" value = "/example", consumes = ".." , method= "..")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Object", value = "Object to be created", required = true, dataType = "your.package.BodyClass", paramType = "body")
})
@RequestMapping(name = "xxx" value ="/hello" ..)
@ApiResponses(..)
    public @ResponseBody String getXXX (@Apiparam(name="JSONrequest", required = true) @RequestBody String JSONrequest){

}
```

(not sure if you still need the `@Apiparam(name="JSONrequest", required = true)` bit from the method parameter)

Comment: Hi sfat, Thanks. I tried @ApiImplicitParams but still no luck. Posted a bug @ https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2183. I am using version 2..7.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. My Service Class takes @RequestBody argument in String.
So, what I did :

Created a POJO and used @RequestBody annotation with it instead of inputString.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/entity/{entityId}/user/query", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> queryUser(@PathVariable("entityId") String entityId,
                                      @RequestBody QueryUserJsonSchemaPOJO queryUserJsonSchemaPOJO, String inputString,
                                     HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
            return userService.queryUserService(inputString, entityId, request);
    }
```

Created an AOP with @Around annotation which update the inputString argument.

```
    @Around(value = "execution(* com.athmin.rest.UserController.*(..)) || execution(* com.athmin.rest.CityController.*(..)), and args(..) " +
                " && @annotation(com.athmin.annotations.JSONSchemaFileName) ")
        public Object validateRequestBodyAgainstJsonSchema(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    
        Object[] modifiedArgs = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
        
        for (Object o : proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
                if (o instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) o;
                    requestBody = httpServletRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
                }
            });
        
for (int i = 0; i < modifiedArgs.length; i++) {
            if (modifiedArgs[i] == null) { // Only inputString is null in my case
                modifiedArgs[i] = requestBody;
            }
        }
        
            proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(modifiedArgs);
    }
```